# 16.04 - issues with metrics when ethernet and wifi are plugged in

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, ifconfig

After upgrading to 16.04 on a lot of our laptops we have noticed that the networking has changed and the WiFi adapter automatically get's a higher metric 600 compared to the Ethernet which has a 0 metric.

The issue we have is that we connect the Ethernet to a closed network with no internet and the WiFi to a network that has internet connection, which has to be done for a number of location issues, and we have to use a fixed IP for Ethernet.

What we get is the networking will always try to use the Ethernet to get the internet connection and never the WiFi, even with the Ethernet unplugged it's still trying to route via  Ethernet.

This was never an issue in 14.04 and at the moment we have to bring down adapters to get the internet to work.

Has anyone else seen this before? and whats the best solution to change this?

Could change the metric but if a laptop connects to a different WiFi source then we have to change it again? Is there a better solution to change the networking back to how it use to be in 14.04?

Thanks

```
  ping 8.8.8.8

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.205 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.205 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.205 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.205 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.205 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.205 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.205 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.205 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, +8 errors, 100% packet loss, time 7038ms
pipe 3


ifconfig

enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:e7:f4:f1:c3:9e  
          inet addr:192.168.0.205  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:e1200000-e1220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:62836 (62.8 KB)  TX bytes:62836 (62.8 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e4:a7:a0:a6:f7:34  
          inet addr:10.154.58.100  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::50c5:514:7923:172c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20862 (20.8 KB)  TX bytes:20668 (20.6 KB)



route -n 

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s31f6
0.0.0.0         10.128.128.128  0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s31f





more /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
address 192.168.0.205
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to change metric on ethernet connection.
Change interface setup to something like

```
/etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
address 192.168.0.205
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
up route add default gw 192.168.0.1 metric 1000
down route del default gw 192.168.0.1
```

This will add metric to `ethernet` to `1000` aka more then `wifi`. Is `wifi`  connected and traffic will be routed to `wifi`. If `wifi` is not connected traffic will be router to `eth`. If `wifi` is connected and `eth` is also connected, traffic will be routed trough `wifi` because of metric witch is `600` for `wifi` and `1000` for `eth` Also if `eth` is disconnected command `down route del default gw 192.168.0.1` will delete default route to `eth`.